# How to combine value in multiple rows into one row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I did a pivot table, so A, B, C, D refer to the same column, so far my data look like below

```
A | B | C | D
1 |   |   |
  | 1 |   |
  |   | 1 |
  |   |   | 1
```

How can I combine these rows into one row like below?

```
 A | B | C | D
 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Comment: Apply aggregation with `MAX`/`MIN`. Use `GROUP BY` if your table involves partitions.

Comment: you need a column that determines which rows belong together